# Can I make a request to an HTTP API server without opening myself up to vulnerabilities?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, security, axios

I am building an API server using Node.js and Express. My server has a route which requires important data from a 3rd party, so I would like to make a request to their API using axios.

My problem is that the 3rd party's API endpoints are http://..., not https://. As a result, I get the following error:

> (node:7088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: api.<3rdpartysite>.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:www.<3rdpartysite>.com, DNS:<3rdpartysite>.com

I know that it is up to the 3rd party to fix their API so I can access it via HTTPS. I have reached out to the API developer repeatedly for weeks with no response.

I can make things *work* by setting the environment variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` , but I know that opens up significant security risks.

Here is the code I am currently using to make the request:

```
app.post("/api/v0/myRoute", async (req, res) => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `http://api.<3rdpartysite>.com/v0/theirRoute? 
       apikey=${keys.thirdpartysite}`
    );
    console.log(response);
});
```

Changing the `http` above to `https` gives me the exact same error message.

I want to make this request without putting my own API server at risk. Is there a way?

Comment: Show the code you are using to make your request?

Comment: All done! @tbking

Comment: Looks like your http url is being redirected to an improperly set up https server. Try passing this config to axios: `axios.get(<url>, { httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }) })`. Here https is node https module.

Comment: Note that not rejecting an invalid certificate is pretty much the same as not using https at all. As you don't authenticate the 3rd party, you can be talking to (and sending/receiving data to/from) anybody. You cannot make this secure on your end, the 3rd party needs to act on this.